# Excel Workbook External Links not updating when saved on network drive.

Tags: excel, hyperlink, updating

I have two spreadsheets, one a source document that has data inputted and the other a destination document.

Both of these sheets are saved to a network drive, the cells are linked through the "=SOURCE!$A$1" type formula.

If i have both spreadsheets opened on the same computer they work swimmingly, but as soon as I open one on one computer and the other on another they no longer update.

Excuse my beginnerness, this is the first time i have attempted to do this, it may be impossible, but if i thought it works on one computer then why isn't it working on another.

I really need them to update in real time :) Both the source and destination are shared.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers, 
Logan

Comment: So on Computer1 two files are saved: `File1` which has links to `File2` (which stores data).  The links work fine when you open `File1` on `Computer1`.  However, when you open `File1` on `Computer2`, the links do not function. (is that correct so far?)    **Question:** are you opening the *original* copy of `File1` on `Computer2` (via a shared folder), or is this a *separate copy* of `File1` (that was emailed or otherwise copied from `Computer1` to `Computer2`)?

Comment: *(cont'd)* ...  What I'm trying to determine is if you have a *share* of some sort setup between the two computers. **Example:**  If the *only* copy of `File2` (the data source) is located on `Computer1`, are you still able to open `File2` from `Computer2`.  If not, or if you're not sure, that's your issue and you'll need to either create a share, or contact your I.T. department to help you with that

Comment: Hi, What is happening is this

The original source sits on the network drive, and the destination file also sits in the same network location. The links are correctly syntaxed to reference the correct network location. 

File 1 is open on computer 1, File 2 is open on computer two

File 1 has links to file 2

Both these files are opened from the network drive location.

Comment: What if File 2 is not opened on **either** computer?  Does File 1 work properly on both Computer1 *and* Computer2?

Comment: File 2 has to be opened.

Comment: ..."has to be opened"?  or else what?

Comment: So in short, 

File 2 has a field for times that a task is completed
File 1 has that time entered into it. 

I need it to real time transpose into file 2

Comment: Are you getting an error at all through all this? Or is it "just not updating"?

Comment: ...I'm going to move the above information to an answer along with a couple links that may help

Answer (score 0):

In your [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50093138/excel-workbook-external-links-not-updating-when-saved-on-network-drive?noredirect=1#comment87203065_50093138) you clarified that `File1` and `File2` both need to opened at the same time, as they both require human interaction in order to function.

This implies that `File2` isn't really a *"data file"* per-se.  **Data Files** are by definition used only for data storage and have no live interaction.

Your setup is an unusual one (having two Excel files that both require interaction and are dependent on each other being open to function).  If this functions properly with both files open on the *same* computer, then this is likely a **file-locking** and/or **permissions** issue, and I'm not sure you'll be able to get around it as-is.

---

### Potential Solutions:

1. Migrate your entire setup to **Microsoft Access**, which is designed to handle record locking and database splitting that is necessary for multi-user environments. ([More info](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20140728120923-4665957-yes-microsoft-access-works-in-a-multi-user-environment/))
2. Create a 3rd Excel file (an *actual* data file that is to remain closed) and have Excel files `1` and `2` both link to it, using `File3` as the "go-between".
3. Create an Access `ACCDB` file as the "go-between" data-storage location location, and have Excel files `1` and `2` both link to it, since the `ACCBD` can have many connected computers/users regardless of whether it's opened or closed.

-

In order to get this working with Excel, you'll need to figure out the network shares/permissions necessary to open the two files simultaneously with [***asynchronous file locks***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/asynchronous-file-i-o), which is more of a network admin topic.

Asynchronous file locking is a built-in feature of Microsoft Access.

---

## More Information:

- Wikipedia : [**Data File** (definition)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_file)
- Microsoft Docs : [**Asynchronous File I/O**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/io/asynchronous-file-i-o)
- LinkedIn : [**Yes, Microsoft Access works in a Multi-User Environment**](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20140728120923-4665957-yes-microsoft-access-works-in-a-multi-user-environment/)
- Office.com : [**Move data from Excel to Access**](https://support.office.com/article/move-data-from-excel-to-access-90c35a40-bcc3-46d9-aa7f-4106f78850b4)
- Stack Exchange : [**Server Fault**](https://serverfault.com/)
  <sup>Q&A for system and network administrators</sup>
- Stack Exchange : [**Super User**](https://superuser.com/)
  <sup>Q&A for computer enthusiasts and power users</sup>